# HTML5 How to post image in src to server

Tags: html, post, crop

Ok this is simple. I have an image the user crops with a library called `Croppie`, I show the image to the user in a `<img src="..">` I populate when the image is cropped. Then. I want to send the cropped image to the server ... how can I do that? Can I get the image from the `src` attribute and `post` it somehow?

Comment: Do you have an example of what the src=".." actually has in it?

Comment: It has an image that has been cropped with Croppie: http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/ . Just don't know how to send it to the server.

Comment: Why the downvote? Comment plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the image into a Canvas and then get the image as base64 string from it. You can post the string to the server and build an image with it.